# Error in source() unexpected numeric constant

Tags: r, rstudio

when I write an R script in a `test.R` file

```
nb <- 22

paste("Etudions le nombre: ",nb)
paste("Le logarithme népérien de ce nombre est: ", log(nb))
paste("La racine carrée de ce nombre est: ", sqrt(nb))
paste("Le cosinus de ce nombre est: ", cos(nb))
paste("Si on ajoute 3 au nombre ", nb, " on obtient: ", nb + 3)

q("ask")
```

I executed using :

```
source("/Users/shous/Desktop/Master2.0/LanguageR/test.R")
```

error  message :

```
Error in source("/Users/shous/Desktop/Master2.0/LanguageR/test.R") :
/Users/shous/Desktop/Master2.0/LanguageR/test.R:1:9: unexpected numeric constant
1: nbÂ <-Â 22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be encoding problem: `unexpected numeric constant 1: nbÂ <-Â 22`

I guess you don't want to have this character `Â`.Try to change file encoding or rewrite problematic line (not copy paste).

Answer (score 0):

> `unexpected numeric constant 1: nbÂ <-Â 22`

This is R telling you that it found the line

```
nbÂ <-Â 22
```

and that isn't valid syntax. You can duplicate this simply on the command line with something like `a = a 22`, which also isn't valid syntax. You need to correct that line of code - I don't know what you want it to be, perhaps there is a missing line break, or perhaps it should be `Â + 22` or `Â[22]`, etc...

The line that produces the error does not occur in the code you show, perhaps you should make sure you are running the right file.